# Laravel: ¿Cómo agregar un elemento al principio de un objeto devuelto por una consulta en eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

tengo el resultado de una consulta vía eloquent de este modo:

```
$bases = Base::select('id','nombre')->orderBy('nombre','ASC')->get();
```

Eh intentado agregar un elemento al inicio (como si fuera un elemento mas de lo que recupero en la base de datos), pero no eh tenido exito, eh probado con `$bases->appends('id','0');` o `$bases->append(['id'=>'hola']);`; también probé con algo como:  `$bases[] = (object) ["id"=>0,"nombre"=>"Cualquier Operador"];` el resultado si imprimo $bases es casi el esperado, porque conserva la estructura (a simple vista) pero no aparece al inicio como dese y al mandarlo a la vista dice "cannot use object of type stdClass as array",

La consulta retorna lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo espero obtener algo como:

```
[{"id":0,"nombre":"Cualquier Operador"},{"id":5,"nombre":"ABASOLO"},{"id":11,"nombre":"COMPRAS"},{"id":1,"nombre":"GUADALAJARA"},{"id":10,"nombre":"HUEHUETOCA"},{"id":6,"nombre":"MANZANILLO"},{"id":3,"nombre":"PUEBLA"},{"id":4,"nombre":"TOLUCA"},{"id":8,"nombre":"TULA"},{"id":2,"nombre":"ZAPOPAN"},{"id":7,"nombre":"ZAPOPAN1"},{"id":9,"nombre":"ZAPOPAN2"},{"id":12,"nombre":"ZAPOPAN3"}]
```

En la vista, utilizado el resultado de esa consulta para llenar un select que despliego mediante un template:

```
@include('templates.dynamic-select',['divId' => 'base_id_wrap',
    'label' => 'Base',
    'required' => true,
    'selectId' => 'base_id',
    'pairAttributes' => ["data-parsley-group" => "viaje","data-parsley-class-handler" => "#base_id_wrap .btn", "data-parsley-errors-container" => "#base-id-message"],
    'singleAttributes' => ['data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled','data-size=5', isset($bases) ? '' : 'disabled' ],
    'defaultLabelSelected' => '--Seleccione la Base--',
    'fields' => isset($bases) ? $bases : $base,
    'conditional' => isset($bases) ? '' : $base[0]->id,
    'value' => 'nombre'])
```

El template es el siguiente:

```
        @php
        $required = isset($required) && !empty($required) ? $required : false;
    @endphp

<div id="{{ $divId }}" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{ $selectId }}">{{ $label }} @if($required)<span class="required">*</span> @endif</label>
    <select id="{{ $selectId }}" name="{{ $selectId }}" class="form-control selectpicker dropdown {{ $selectClass or '' }}" @if($required) required @endif
            data-live-search="true"
            @if(isset($pairAttributes))
                @foreach($pairAttributes as $key => $data)
                    {{ $key }}  =  "{{ $data }}"
                @endforeach
            @endif
            @if(isset($singleAttributes))
                @foreach($singleAttributes as $attr)
                    {{ $attr. ' ' }}
                @endforeach
            @endif
            title="{{ $defaultLabelSelected }}">
        @foreach ($fields as $field)
            <option value="{{ isset($value) ? $field->id : $field }}"  >{{ isset($value) ? $field[$value] : $field}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @if(isset($conditional) && !empty($conditional))
            $('#{{ $selectId }}').val({{$conditional}});
            $("#{{ $selectId }} option[value='{{$conditional}}']").attr("selected", true);
        @endif
    </script>
@endpush
```

Reitero que si lo mando como lo recibo de la consulta si funciona.

Agradeceria su ayuda!

Comment: Podrías darnos un retorno de lo que te trae esa consulta, creo que lo tuyo se resolvería con un put, porque recuerda que laravel te trae una coleccion.

Comment: listo, agregue imagen y resultado esperado

Comment: push te debe ayudar, algo como `$bases->push(['id' => 0, 'name' => 'Cualquier Operador']);`

Comment: @BetaM al mandarlo a la vista me muestra: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @FelipeUrcia devuelve: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @BetaM listo, que sugieres en base a eso?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es prepend
ejemplo

```
$bases->prepend(['id' => 0, 'name' => 'Cualquier Operador']);
```

Puedes ver sobre la informacion en
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-prepend

Comment: A la hora de mandarlo a la vista no funciona, utilizo laravel 5.4

Comment: @ArmandoGileta te debe funcionar, aqui tienes la evidencia: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-prepend